# Unable to load appsettings.json file inside a custom library from ASPNETCORE 6. 0 Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, asp.net-core-6.0

I have created azure function on ASP.NET core 6.0.

from below startup.cs file appsettings.json file is getting loaded without any issue.
It is reading file from D:\Functions\Engagements.Function\Engagements.Function\bin\Debug\net6.0

```
`  public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {

      var executionContextOptions = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()
         .GetService<IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions>>().Value;
      var currentDirectory = executionContextOptions.AppDirectory;

      var config= new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName)
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
      .Build();
}
```

`
while I am trying to load appsettings.json from other library from same azure function it is throwing error:
**A host error has occurred during startup operation 'jh408d9c-d635-47bd-af52-43afdb50a484'.
[2023-04-17T10:44:30.571Z] System.Private.CoreLib: The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The expected physical path was 'C:\Users\HK2769561\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.35.0\cli_x64\appsettings.json'.**

Please check below code.

.`

```
 public EngagementKeyVault()
    {
      _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();
    }
```

`

Comment: Right click on the `appsettings.json` file => in `Properties` => make sure `copy to output` location is set to `Copy if newer` / `copy always`.

Comment: And also check whether you are getting the correct path with `Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName`.

Comment: Check what is the path you are getting using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` .

Comment: Getting Currect path using Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), But what would be  the difference between Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName and Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

Comment: Are you getting the same path (path of appsettings.json) using `Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName`?

Comment: Yes, I am getting same path

Comment: The issue might be with the IConfiguration.In `EngagementKeyVault()` try with the below code. `private readonly IConfiguration myconfig;

    public EngagementKeyVault(IConfiguration config)
    {
        myconfig = config;
    }`

Comment: Instead of `_configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()`, try the above code.

Comment: Could you please share your Application folder structure Image ?

Comment: Where is your `appsettings.json` file located?